# electron can't get current file path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, electron

I'm writing a desktop application with `electron` and `react`. I use `create-react-app` in my project, and I run `npm run start` first to run my app at `http://localhost:3000` and then in the `index.js` of `electron`:

```
win.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? 
           "localhost:3000":path.join(__dirname, 'build/index.html'),
        protocol: 'http:',
        slashes: true
    }));
}
```

You see, when developing I want to use `webpack-dev-server` to hod reload my component so `electron` run the online content which is hold by `webpack-dev-server`.  Everything seems OK, but when I use `fs` to read local files like this:

```
// /src/components/SideBar.js
fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname,'./src/actions/index.js'),(err,data)=>{
    if(err){
         throw err;
         return;
    }
    // ...
})
```

it comes the error that can't find the file, and I tried to alert the result path:

```
alert(path.join(__dirname,'./test.txt'))
```

It shows that the path is `/test.txt`, but the real path is `/project/src/test.txt`.  And I found that :

```
alert(__filename);
```

it is always `/index.js` in any files.

I'm so confused.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to __dirname, you could use the node process module. I just confirmed that for my electron project this returns the full path of the root folder of my source code:

```
import process from 'process';
console.log(`path: ${process.cwd()});
```